# Sinatra: Where do I put my gem dependencies?

Tags: sinatra

I'm coming from a Rails background, where there is a `Gemfile` in each project. I'm trying to learn Sinatra now, and realize I need to install the Nokogiri gem. Where would I list my dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same thing as in Rails just add a `Gemfile`

You may would look at a template project https://github.com/zapnap/sinatra-template

Comment: Great reference. Thanks Sir